# why do I get -1 when i try to delete an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I checked out the questions that were already posted, but I still couldn't find a solution.

My output for the code is:

> Enter the number of integers: 5
>   Enter 5 integers:     1
>        2
>        3
>        4
>   5
>   Enter the number to be deleted: 2
>   -1

---

```
package array;

import java.util.*;
//import java.util.ArrayLists; 

public class DeleteFromArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 0; // number of integers
        int d = 0; // the number to be deleted
        int count = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of integers: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        int[] buffer = new int[n];
        System.out.print("Enter " + n + " integers: ");

        for (int k = 0; k < buffer.length; k++) {
            buffer[k] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the number to be deleted: ");
        d = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == d) {
                for (int j = 0; j < (buffer.length) - 1; j++) {
                    buffer[j] = buffer[j + 1];
                }
                count++;
                break;
            }

        }
        if(count ==0) {
            System.out.println("Element not found!");
        }
        else {
             System.out.print("Element Deleted Successfully..!!");
               System.out.print("\nNow the New Array is :\n");
               for (int i = 0; i < (buffer.length)-1; i++) {
                System.out.println(buffer[i]+ " ");
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  With your input, I get "Element Deleted Successfully..!!" "Now the New Array is :" 2 3 4 5, which looks incorrect, presumably due to how you're initializing `j`.

Comment: Should be `for (int j = i; j < buffer.length - 1; j++) {....`

Comment: Or this: `for (int j = i + 1; j < buffer.length; j++) { buffer[j-1] = buffer[j]; }`

Comment: johnny and remy, I tried both, but i am still getting -1

Comment: I don't see where it would print -1. Do you need to recompile? There's no error message?

Comment: Works fine here:https://ideone.com/YE5Xc2

Comment: The problem with your output is that it is not possible with that code, you should either have "_Element not found!_" or "_Element Deleted Successfully..!!_" ... but you have "_-1_". Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < (buffer.length) - 1; j++) {
                buffer[j] = buffer[j + 1];
            }
```

will not work properly because it will replace the value at 0 index with the value at index 1 and so on. What you want to do is just intialize the `j=i` where i is the index of `d`. and it will replace this value with the next.

```
for (int j = i; j < (buffer.length) - 1; j++) { 
                    buffer[j] = buffer[j + 1];
                }
```

Try this loop it will work.

Comment: Ok I will explaining.

Comment: Ok Sir, now it is fine.

Comment: That's indeed much better.